# Rails 4 Tableless Model with Validations

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

In rails 4.0.5 I set up a tableless model. So I have a form that takes info but when i attempt to validate the info it doenst work. Validations will return 'canot be blank' on all fields even if the field is filled. What am I doing wrong.

*form*

```
 = form_for @bank do |f|
   = f.text_field :first_name
   = f.text_field :account
   = f.text_field :routing
   = f.text_field :zip
   %button{:type => "submit"} Submit
```

*controller*

```
 class BanksController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @bank = Bank.new
   end

   def create  
     @bank = Bank.new(params[bank_params])
     if @bank.valid?  
     # etc.... 
   end  
 end
```

*model*

```
 class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base  
   def self.columns() @columns ||= []; end  
   def self.column(name, sql_type = nil, default = nil, null = true)  
     columns << ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new(name.to_s, default, sql_type.to_s, null)  
   end  

     column :first_name, :string 
     column :account,    :int
     column :routing,    :int
     column :zip,        :int

     VALID_NUM_REGEX = /\A[+-]?\d+\z/    

     validates :first_name, presence: true
     validates :account, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_NUM_REGEX }, length:  { minimum: 4 }
     validates :routing, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_NUM_REGEX }, length:  { minimum: 4 }
 end
```

*Console*

```
 Started POST "/banks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-09 11:39:40 -0400
  Processing by BanksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"..=","bank"=>{"first_name"=>"Alain", "account"=>"1234", "routing"=>"4321","zip"=>"11413"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's wrong, but my guess is it has to do with your overriding of `columns` and `column`.  I'd strongly suggest that you use a plain Ruby object and then include ActiveModel::Validations.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html

From that page:

```
class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

  validates_each :first_name, :last_name do |record, attr, value|
    record.errors.add attr, 'starts with z.' if value.to_s[0] == ?z
  end
end
```

Which provides you with the full standard validation stack that you know from Active Record:

```
person = Person.new
person.valid?                   # => true
person.invalid?                 # => false

person.first_name = 'zoolander'
person.valid?                   # => false
person.invalid?                 # => true
person.errors.messages          # => {first_name:["starts with z."]}
```

Comment: When i do it like this exactly here: https://gist.github.com/alaingoldman/09ff02f122ff7408acee

I get the error: undefined method `to_key' for #<Bank:0xc3be424>

Comment: You probably need some of the others... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html

Comment: I get the same thing if i do this:  https://gist.github.com/alaingoldman/04f766d941d064d5aaa3